# Is there a way to make git flow show the commands it is executing behind the scenes?

Tags: git, git-flow

Is there any way to make git-flow tell me ahead of time the exact git commands it will execute when I do a flow command; or tell me as it is dong it?

All i can see the output and a summary?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Git's `GIT_TRACE` [environment variable](http://git-scm.com/docs/git#_environment_variables) to get a detailed trace of commands executed.  For example:

```
GIT_TRACE=true git flow feature start bar
```

... displays ...

```
trace: exec: 'git-flow' 'feature' 'start' 'bar'
trace: run_command: 'git-flow' 'feature' 'start' 'bar'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get' 'gitflow.branch.master'
trace: built-in: git 'branch' '--no-color'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get' 'gitflow.branch.develop'
trace: built-in: git 'branch' '--no-color'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get' 'gitflow.branch.master'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get' 'gitflow.branch.develop'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get' 'gitflow.branch.master'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get' 'gitflow.branch.develop'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get' 'gitflow.origin'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get' 'gitflow.prefix.feature'
trace: built-in: git 'branch' '--no-color'
trace: built-in: git 'branch' '-r' '--no-color'
trace: built-in: git 'branch' '--no-color'
trace: built-in: git 'branch' '-r' '--no-color'
trace: built-in: git 'checkout' '-b' 'feature/bar' 'develop'
Switched to a new branch 'feature/bar'

Summary of actions:
- A new branch 'feature/bar' was created, based on 'develop'
- You are now on branch 'feature/bar'

Now, start committing on your feature. When done, use:

     git flow feature finish bar
```

If you want more details than that, you can use the [`sh` shell](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sh) `xtrace` option:

> After expanding each simple command, for command, case command, select command, or arithmetic for command, display the expanded value of PS4, followed by the command and its expanded arguments or associated word list.

Edit the `git-flow` script and add `set -x` right after the `#!/bin/sh` first line.  Executing the above command, `git flow feature start bar`, would display a lot of information (more than can be included in an answer).

Answer (score 5):

Use the `--showcommands` switch, for instance:

```
git flow feature start FEATURENAME --showcommands
```

Answer (score 1):

[Some commands have a verbose flag](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments), but I believe the answer to your question is "No".

Answer (score 1):

You can see what each command does by checking [the source](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow). It’s well documented so you can understand what is happening even without knowing bash.

Actually, after checking the source, there indeed seems to be a way to log the commands git flow uses internally; at least most of them. The functionality was introduced [with this commit](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/commit/5bca8d9358f5b08af40ac32f289bb14b18965cec) and hints of a `show_commands` setting. You should be able to enable it using `--show_commands`, and it will print out most git commands it uses internally.