# How to see application logs for git client

Tags: git

I have setup a [`cntlm`](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) based proxy on my system. I've pointed git to use this proxy by adding following to my `.gitconfig` file.

```
[http]
       proxy = http://:@localhost:3128
```

However when I run `git clone` from commandline it shows me this error -

```
error: Failed connect to github.com:443; Connection timed out while accessing
```

I've tested the proxy with firefox and it works.

How do I find out more information about why git is failing? Where do I see the logs for `git` client.

Comment: You might use something like tcpdump or Wireshark to see what traffic is coming and going.

Comment: Are you actually cloning with an http url? That is, do you do `git clone http://github.com/...` ?

Comment: @JimmyKane Curl gives me html. Which means that it is connectible.

Comment: What exactly does that `html` say? You might be getting an error page html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the syntax without ':', and set it for http and https, as illustrated in "[How to point Git to use cntlm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13230636/6309)"

```
git config --global https.proxy http://localhost:3128
git config --global http.proxy http://localhost:3128
```

You can also run `cntlm.exe -v` to see what is going on.
As well as setting `GIT_TRACE=2` before doing the `git clone`.

Comment: I tried `export GIT_TRACE=2` and it shows trace level log messages. See this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15440291/1345655).